# How to amplify codegen models?

Tags: android, graphql-java, aws-amplify

Model :

```
type Order @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  orderDate: AWSDate
  qrcode: String
  address: String
  allergies: String
  deliveryOption: DeliveryOptions
  deliveryType: DeliveryType
  paymentMethod: String
  orderItems: [OrderItem] @connection(keyName: "byOrder", fields: ["id"])
  addresss: Address @connection
  vehicleDescription: Car @connection
  friendsAndFamily: FriendsAndFamily @connection
}
```

I execute "amplify codegen models" in terminal  for android studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYRcr.png)

But it has error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZlcM.png)

I can delete first constructor in field and continute work, but when i rexecute "amplify codegen models", it error.

Please help me!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of the Amplify CLI generates models that are only compatible with Amplify Android version 1.16.11 or later.  The latest version is 1.16.15.  Please update to the latest library version.